# SetCancelable and Back Button (android)

Tags: android

I have an app and When the user presses BACK Button, it shows dialog, the dialog cannot be cancelled so I set it `setCancelable(false)`

but I want to dismiss the dialog when the user presses BACK button Again.
(
if the user presses Back Button, Show dialog.
if the user presses Back Button again , dismiss dialog
)

My Code below

```
private boolean dialogshown = false;
private AlertDialog d;
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {   
  if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    if(!dialogshown) {
        d = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        d.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        dialogshown = false;
                    }
                });
        d.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Exit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
        d.setCancelable(false);
        d.show();
        dialogshown = true;
    } else {
        try{ d.dismiss(); }catch (Exception exc){Toast.makeText(this,"Error back",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    }
return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

The problem is when I press Back button it shows a dialog, but when I press it again Nothing Happens

Comment: the solution is  `d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;
     public void onBackPressed() {
            if(alertDialog == null || !alertDialog.isShowing()){
                alertDialog = = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Delete entry")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
            }else{
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
}
```

No need to maintain any extra variable to do this.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for Help , But unfortunately it's not working

Comment: Your Code works  but when I `setCancelable(false)` It does not work

Comment: Didn't get your context, If you set setCancelable false then it will not respond on any key press, unless it's own buttons. So my question is why you need to setCancelable value false.

Answer (score -1):

Put a boolean for dialog is open or not.

```
isDialogOpen = false
```

And override the backpress. When user pressed this method will called.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isDialogOpen==false){
                d.show();
                 isDialogOpen == true;
            }
            else {
                isDialogOpen == false;
                d.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
     }
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

edit: thanks akyirem samuel